# how to use binary in python test in bazel

Tags: python, bazel-rules

I want to test cc_binay in bazel with py_test rule, how can I access the cc_binary in python file?
My bazel BUILD file is:

```
py_test(
    name = 'simple_test',
    size = 'small',
    srcs = ['simple_test.py'],
    data = [':simple'],    # the tested cc_binary
)
```

Can anybody give me a example? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

cc_binary can be added as data dependency as below.

```
cc_binary(
    name = "my-bin",
    srcs = ["bin.cc"],
)

py_test(
    name = "my-test",
    srcs = ["my_test.py"],
    data = [":my-bin"],
    # any other attributes you need...
)
```